# GridSearchCV inconsistent k-fold from scikit-learn 0.18.1 too 0.19.0

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I'm trying to switch from `sklearn.grid_search` to `sklearn.model_selection`.

Why does `GridSearchCV` yields totally different amount of k-folds in `scikit-learn==0.18.1` than in `scikit-learn==0.19.0`?

```
all_estimator_scores = []

def custom_multi_class_scorer(estimator, X, y_truth):

    y_pred = estimator.predict(X)

    # Collect scores
    acc = accuracy_score(y_truth, y_pred)
    estimator_score = []
    estimator_score.append(acc)
    estimator_score.append(f1_score(y_truth, y_pred, average='macro'))
    estimator_score.append(precision_score(y_truth, y_pred, average='macro'))
    estimator_score.append(recall_score(y_truth, y_pred, average='macro'))
    estimator_score.append(f1_score(y_truth, y_pred, average='micro'))
    estimator_score.append(precision_score(y_truth, y_pred, average='micro'))
    estimator_score.append(recall_score(y_truth, y_pred, average='micro'))

    # Save scores
    all_estimator_scores.append(estimator_score)

    # Return number between 0.0 and 1.0 (score)
    return acc

def run_experiment(clf, tuned_parameters, X, y):
    gscv = GridSearchCV(clf, tuned_parameters, cv=10, scoring=custom_multi_class_scorer)
    gscv.fit(X, y)
    print len(all_estimator_scores)

tuned_parameters = [{'alpha': [0.0001, .001, .01, .1, 1.0]}]
experimentor.run_experiment(MultinomialNB(), tuned_parameters, X, y)
```

Output `scikit-learn==0.18.1`:

```
50
```

Output `scikit-learn==0.19.0`:

```
100
```

Comment: I just guess, maybe sklearn enhanced the algorithm?

Comment: Yeah, fit(X,y) new takes test data? there is a new "group" parameter, haven't figured out how that works yet.